# Is it possible in Robot Framework to define a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to have a list in a dictionary, example:

The dictionary `data` has to entries: `name` and `modes`. `modes` should be a list that I can later access using `${data.modes}`. Here's what I tried:

```
&{data}           name=Jeff    modes=['online', 'offline']
```

Calling `modes` retrieves a string. I tested it by getting the index of the element `online`, which returned **2** while it should be **0**.

Is saving a list in a dictionary possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Bryan Oakley said, or the old-fashioned way - set as a value any list variable you have defined already:

```
@{my list}      online    offline
&{data}         name=Jeff    modes=${my list}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with robot 3.2 you can use [inline python evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#inline-python-evaluation), which lets you put almost any code between `${{` and `}}`:

```
&{data}    name=Jeff  modes=${{ ['online', 'offline'] }}
```

Comment: I'm in Robot framework 3.0 and can't upgrade, won't be able to test this.